# Shift+arrow to change window does not work in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I installed a package that changes emacs windows using Shift+arrow, and it works in various modes I use but not in org-mode.  Is there a reason why org-mode shadows this command?

Comment: The following link demonstrates how to disable a few `org-mode-map` key bindings:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17540326/2112489  That approach will permit global key bindings to be used again.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the package for window changing you are referring to (`windmove`?). Have a look at http://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me, I have now found it in my init file.  It is `framemove`.

Comment: @AlejandroErickson OK. The org-mode Conflicts section should help for that too. Check out the CUA and windmove sections over there.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your config, like described in ["Packages that conflict with Org mode"](https://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html):

```
(add-hook 'org-shiftup-final-hook 'windmove-up)
(add-hook 'org-shiftleft-final-hook 'windmove-left)
(add-hook 'org-shiftdown-final-hook 'windmove-down)
(add-hook 'org-shiftright-final-hook 'windmove-right)
```

Set `org-support-shift-select` customization variable to *"Everywhere except timestamps"* `(setq org-support-shift-select 'always)`, otherwise shift+arrows will still have org-mode keybidnings on headings.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs 26.2 you only need to set the variable `org-replace-disputed-keys` to true while enabling `windmove-default-keybindings` to have the default windmove keybindings work normally. You don't need to configure the variable `org-support-shift-select` as said by [the answer of kolen](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38443/15868) if you don't need the shift selection function because enabling default windmove keybindings will disable shift selection automatically (see `C-h i g (emacs)Window Convenience`). You only need to add

```
(add-hook 'org-shiftup-final-hook 'windmove-up)
(add-hook 'org-shiftleft-final-hook 'windmove-left)
(add-hook 'org-shiftdown-final-hook 'windmove-down)
(add-hook 'org-shiftright-final-hook 'windmove-right)
```

to init file if you want to keep the original org mode keybindings on regions where they take effect such as headings or list items and enable windmove on other regions (see `C-h i g (org)conflicts`). You may need to restart Emacs after making these changes to let them take effect.