# Shift+Ctrl+arrow to enlarge and shrink windows does not work in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, window

Similarly to what is described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/shiftarrow-to-change-window-does-not-work-in-org-mode), org-mode overrides `C-S-<arrow>` key-binds which, in order to control the size of the windows, I have defined as follows:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<right>") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<left>") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<up>") 'enlarge-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<down>") 'shrink-window)
```

I would expect an identical solution to work, i.e.:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-ctrl-shiftright-final-hook 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(add-hook 'org-ctrl-shiftleft-final-hook 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(add-hook 'org-ctrl-shiftup-final-hook 'enlarge-window)
(add-hook 'org-ctrl-shiftdown-final-hook 'shrink-window)
```

However the above has no effect at all. In `org-mode` those keys are still bind to setting and clearing marks (up/down combinations) and to work with the clock log (right/left combinations). In particular, they are bound to `org-shiftcontrolup` (and similar for the remaining three).

Does someone know how can one successfully override these key-binds in `org-mode`?

Comment: There is no variable `org-ctrl-shiftright-final-hook` (or any  of the other directions) defined in Org mode and therefore *nobody runs such a hook*. You can define such variables as you have done above and you can add functions to them,  but you might as well be defining a variable called, say, `beubeu` or `nickd` and expecting something to happen: if nobody uses the variable, then it doesn't matter what its value is - nobody uses it and so it might as well not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `org-mode-map` like this:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "S-C-<left>") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "S-C-<right>") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "S-C-<down>") 'shrink-window)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "S-C-<up>") 'enlarge-window)
```

Comment: ... assuming that you don't care about the functionality that Org mode assigned to those keys in the first place.

Comment: @djangoliv Thank you. Do you know why using ```org-ctrl-shift...``` does not work?

Comment: @Beubeu Sorry, but no, I don't know...

Comment: There are no such variables defined in Org mode, so giving them a value does not do anything.