# Terminal (shell) side by side with editor, how to navigate back and forth?

Tags: eshell

I am new to Emacs.  I can invoke a shell or eshell using `M-x shell` or `M-x eshell`.  This created a shell and I can run executables from it.  By default, this shell is in the same window as my source code.  So, I can switch between the source code and the shell using: C-x Right/ Left.

I would like to have this shell to be side by side with my source code.  So, I tried to do : `C-x 3`.  This creates a vertical split. I then have shell on 1 side and source code on the other.  But, how do I switch back and forth between the splits? I can click on which split I want, but I am struggling to find the shortcut to switch.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between windows quickly?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/how-to-switch-between-windows-quickly)

Comment: `C-x o` is what you want.

Comment: @FranBurstall can you re-write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to change from one window to another as you describe is `other-window` which is bound to `C-x o` by default.

Answer (score 0):

For two windows, `C-x o` works just fine.  But what if you want more than two?  Circling through them can be a pain, especially since there's no way to go backwards.

This is why it wasn't long before I discovered [window-number-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NumberedWindows).  There is also [Window Numbering Mode](https://github.com/nschum/window-numbering.el) which has the benefit of being a Melpa package and lets you use Meta+number to switch windows.

Check those out when you start getting tired of `C-x o`