# Switching directly to a certain window

Tags: window

If I have 3 windows beside each other, can I switch to any one of them
without having to look for the cursor first (so I know whether to press
`C-x o` once or twice)?

Is there, for example, or could I easily write, a function that jumped to
the PREFIXth window from the left?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correct, maybe ace-window would be the right thing for you. 
I configured it like this

```
   (use-package ace-window
    :ensure t
    :init
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-c o") 'ace-window))
```

This numbers your windows and you just press the number of the window you want.
Hope this helps.

EDIT:
I think ace-window fits best to Toothrots question. Just to mention, I am mostly using

```
(windmove-default-keybindings)
```

to quickly navigate windows and I am very happy with it.
A more detailed description for that can be found [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3460/21278)

Comment: Don't you want to rather bind it to the key originally bound to `other-window`? (`C-x o`)

Comment: you are right JeanPierre, just a habit, sometimes I use original other-window as well. Maybe your keybinding would be the better choice. I mostly navigate buffers using windmove. Maybe I should edit my answer and add this also.