# Switch between 2 windows?

Tags: window

I'm JUST starting out emacs. On the right half of the screen I have the interpreter and on the left half of the screen I have my code. I want to switch between these 2 using keyboard only (shortcuts). There is Ctrl-x Left/Right but that one changes the buffer(?) in the current window, what I want is to switch the active window. For example if I'm writing code and is done I can click the shortcut and start writing in the interpreter.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Have a look at the Emacs manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html), which will help you find answers to these sorts of questions.

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate question. Please search for tag `[window]` to see. If so, please delete this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch between windows quickly?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/how-to-switch-between-windows-quickly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default Emacs keybindings, you can do this with <kbd>C-x o</kbd>. If you're using evil-mode, you can also use <kbd>C-w C-w</kbd>.

Comment: Very amazing thank you baby boy